# form.is_valid() always returning false

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Form.is_valid() is always returning false, and it never shows any kind of error. Following is the code snippet from forms.py, views.py and template/transaction_add_page.html

**Form**

```
class TransactionForm(forms.Form):
  account = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Account.objects.none())
  transactions = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':'10', 'cols':'70'}))

  def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['account'].queryset = Account.objects.filter(user=user)

  def clean_account(self):
    if 'account' in self.cleaned_data:
      account = self.cleaned_data['account']
      return account
    raise forms.ValidationError('Please select an account.')

  def clean_transactions(self):
    if 'transactions' in self.cleaned_data:
      transactions = self.cleaned_data['transactions']
      return transactions
    raise forms.ValidationError('At-least one transaction is required.')
```

**View**

```
@login_required
def transaction_add_page(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TransactionForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      variables = RequestContext(request, {'account': form.clean_account(), 'transactions': form.clean_transactions()})
      return render_to_response('transaction_confirm_page.html', variables)

  form = TransactionForm(request.user)
  variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
  return render_to_response('transaction_add_page.html', variables)
```

**Template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Add Transactions{% endblock %}
{% block head %}Add Transactions{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="." >
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  {{ form.errors }}

  {% for field in form %}
    <div>
      {{ field.errors }}
      {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

  <input type="submit" value="Add Transactions" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set on the initializer the user argument, you need to use it.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
   form = TransactionForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
```