# Forms hierarchy issue in Django

Tags: django, forms, authentication

I created a form for login, just like this:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField (label=_("Usuario"), max_length=30, 
                widget=forms.widgets.
                TextInput(attrs={'id':'username','maxlength':'25'}))
    password = forms.CharField (label=_("Password"), widget=forms.widgets.
                PasswordInput(attrs={'id':'password','maxlength':'10'}))
```

I use it in this view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                ...
```

After debugging I realize that the form.is_valid() method returns false cause the is_bound attr is false. Do I have to redefine something in my form or to modify my view???

**Edit 1**

I have followed this SO question about is_valid() method returning False:
[form.is_valid() always returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254470/form-is-valid-always-returning-false)

but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually similar to the one in the question you link to. The form you're inheriting from, `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`, takes `request` as its first parameter, before the usual `data` param. This is why your form is reporting that it is not bound - as far as it's concerned, you're not passing in any data, so it has nothing to bind to.

So, in your view, you'll need to instantiate it like this:

```
form = LoginForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue to note about the currently accepted answer:

```
form = LoginForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
```

is that passing in request seems to enable Django's behavior of checking to see if a test cookie was successful before initiating a session. The problem is that if you haven't set the test cookie previously (it has to be set in a previous view request) it will fail and your login will fail. I recommend just passing the data keyword argument in like so:

```
form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
```

Unless I'm missing something important (it didn't seem like the cookie check is absolutely necessary), this works better in most situations. You could alternatively call request.set_test_cookie() in the view that loads the login page, but that doesn't cover all scenarios.